# Allow same user multiple login on different number of devices and how to deal with sessions?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, socket.io

I'm building a chat application with some php, mysql, nodejs, socketio.

I want to allow users to be logged in from nomatterwhat number devices. Like eg. Facebook where it doesn't matter which screen you're looking at. They all reflect the latest changes.
Tested it right now and it works that way. If i open the notifidations the number dissappears on the same page on different devices.

My guess -and started building with that iedea in mind –  was that a room is created for each user when a user logs in the first time and any following login from the same user is also added to that room so the changes can easily be broadcasted to the room.

All browsers are aware off the multiple logins because i send a soclet-message to the room setting a variable - multilogin- so that it knows that there are more.
Also needed to see when a user clicks on the logout-buttons it send that information along.
If it is the only one logged in it should kill the session set the user offline.
Actions performed on one device, broadcasts it to the other members in the room etc.

Seems logical?

It works so far but i'm uncertain about the session part of this setup.

The logic in php -inherited from the origanal build of the chat –  checks the user logging in to see if the user is already logged in and if so, it destroys the existing session first and then sends a loggout command -which i prevent now when the multilogin parameter is send along- to the other browser.

My question now is, what could be a logical approach towards the sessions?

I was playing with some ideas in my head and then i thought, let's look on the internet about the subject.

An idea could be that only the first loggin in gets the session created and is shared by sending the id to the others so they can be identified as being the same user.

Would that be an approach that one would suggest?

Comment: Why is this tagged both node.js and PHP?  Is your server in PHP or node.js?

Comment: @jfriend00 That's because the original chat (ajaxChat) was php. I introduced nodejs and socketio for triggering events and to get rid of the polling (ajax call) by clients by given interval. Eventually i want to get rid off the php part completely. But i don't think it affects the logic of how to deal with single user being on different devices/browsers on the same page. Does it?

Comment: I'm not going to attempt an answer unless you pick a specific back-end environment and target your question at it.  I like to give specific answers, not abstract answers which is why I don't generally answer abstract questions.  Besides, the tools to use for a solution are specific to the back-end environment in use.

Comment: Ok, understandable. Found a simple solution by letting each device with same user that logs in getting a new sessionid which is send to the others (socket message to room) so their sessionid becomes the same to authenticate themselves to the server. Session id is save enough for that purpose. Thanks for your time though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Found a simple solution by letting each device with same user that logs in getting a new sessionid which is send to the others (socket message to room) so their sessionid becomes the same to authenticate themselves to the server. Session id is save enough for that purpose.